# WP-QuickLaTeX rending problem on WordPress hosted by bluehost

Tags: latex

I came across the problem when trying to using QuickLatex on bluehost, but it does not seem to work for me as when I use it in the short code block with the following text.

```
[latexpage]

\[ R =  \left( 1 + {r \over f} \right)^{f}  -1 \]
```

and resulting web page shows

[image]

Comment: That's clearly not the same formula? You might need to debug this yourself: are there any script errors in your browser's debug console, an can you see what the 'X' image is supposed to be / why it's failing to render?

Comment: However you might do better asking the WP-QuickLaTeX plugin authors for help, as they'll know the plugin better than us. I've no idea if Bluehost is significant here or not, but I'd guess not unless you know the same version of the plugin works with the same version of WordPress and theme somewhere else?

Comment: thanks. it looks like it is a cache issue. the default setting is to use cache and the image format is auto as recommended. Using a specific image format make the problem disappeared.